# Is there a way to play more than one sound at once using pygame?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, raspberry-pi3

I have build a set of musical stairs using a pi, motion sensors and python, and a PHP web app to control what instrument is selected. Currently though only one note can be played at a time and I was wondering is there a way of changing the code so that if two motion sensors are passed at once it will produce the effect of a chord?

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb # connect to mysql
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # GPIO
import pygame.mixer # To make sound

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # GPIO set mode
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#Motion sensor setup
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)


while True: 
  #Connect to database
  mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='*****', password='*****', database='*****')
  cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
  cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM settings WHERE active = 'true'")

  for id in cursor:
    print("ID: {}").format(id)
    print type(id[0])

    input_state = GPIO.input(4)
    print("input 4 {}").format(input_state == False)
    if input_state == False:
      if(id[0]==1):
        print "GPIO4 Piano"
        C1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("piano/C1.wav")
        C1.play()

      if(id[0]==2):
          print "GPIO4 Drum"
          drum1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("drum/Drumc1.wav")
          drum1.play()

      if(id[0]==3):
          print "GPIO4 Xylophone"
          X1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("xylophone/X1.wav")
          X1.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixer only supports one stream at a time. So its impossible with mixer

---

You could use both pygame.mixer and winsound if ur using windows: ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎  ‏‏‎ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FyqFqAN9UM